# undefined local variable in chefspec on method included from gem

Tags: rspec, rubygems, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm including a custom gem in a chef cookbook. No matter what I've tried I'm get similar errors to undefined local variable or method `host'

I've tried many different variations to this.

```
allow(HostOpsCookbook).to receive(:host).with(:sonic.version).and_return('10.0')
```

Gem layout

`cust_gem
  \lib
     \ibus
       \host
         sonic.rb
       host.rb`

host.rb

```
module Ibus
  class Host
   attr_reader :sonic

    def initialize
      extend_type
    end

    def enxtend_type
      @sonic = Ibus::Host::Sonic.new
    end

  end
end
```

host\sonic.rb

```
module Ibus
  class Host
    class Sonic

      def version
         .....
      end
  end
 end
end
```

Chef cookbook

`cookbook
  \libraries
     host_helper.rb
  \recipes
     default.rb`

chef\cookbook\libraries\host_helper.rb

```
module HostOpsCookbook
  def host
    require_ibus_gem #Loads the gem
    @@host ||= Ibus::Host.new
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, HostOpsCookbook) if defined?(Chef::Recipe)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, HostOpsCookbook) if defined?(Chef::Resource)
Chef::Provider.send(:include, HostOpsCookbook) if defined?(Chef::Provider)
```

chef\cookbook\recipes\default.rb

```
sonic_version = host.sonic.version
```

This as code works the call to the gem method works.

However I can't figure out how to stub the below in the spec tests.

```
host.sonic.version
```

Comment: to make sure i understand you correctly, you wish to install a rubygem and use it within a recipe?

Comment: Correct, the gem is installed within the chef\cookbook\libraries\host_helper.rb. There are multiple recipes that call different methods from the gem. All that works just fine, the code compiles/converges just fine. It's only during the spec tests that I'm having issues trying to mock/stub anything that calls the method from the gem.

Comment: please update your question to reflect excatly what is the issue and when (you mentioned that it happens durin a test. please specify the framework that you are using. such as chefspec, inspec, etc.)

Comment: It's chefspec, the issue is mentioned above. The exact error is `undefined local variable or method host`

Answer (score 1):

The below code it was ended up working. The version method was nested under the Host/Module, Sonic/Class which is extend when the host object is initialized. This is all shown above.

`allow_any_instance_of(HostOpsCookbook).to receive_message_chain(:host, :sonic, :version).and_return('10.0')`

Answer (score 0):

[You need to install the required rubygem into the environment ChefSpec is running in](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec/issues/871).

This will make sure that the rubygem is resolved by ChefSpec.

Answer (score 0):

```
allow(HostOpsCookbook).to
```

Is for stubbing class methods. You actually have a instance method, so you must use:

```
allow_any_instance_of(<Class>).to
```

Your host method is defined in module, you cannot create an instance from modules. So you must stub the instance of the Chef::Recipe object, as you call *host* method from recipe.

```
allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to
```

Another problem would be stubbing sonic.version. As you try to chain stubbing, you must use [rspec doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/test-doubles) in this case.

So the final result should be:

```
sonic_double = double("Sonic Double", version: "10.0")
allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:host).and_return(sonic_double)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ater, the above was still giving me an issue about unknown method host. But your statement about chain stubbing led me to this which is working.

`allow_any_instance_of(HostOpsCookbook).to receive_message_chain(:host, :sonic, :version).and_return('10.0')`

Comment: @debow Then you should add it as answer to the question and accept it.